# How to control the volume of Rotation of image in RotationAnimation?

Tags: android, rotation

I m making an android app in which rotating discs are continuously rotating while the mediaplayer is playing the music and stops when paused...
the problem is when i increase the duration of rotation in setDuration() method, the speed decreases...
I want to know how can i control the volume of rotation

my code is given below...

```
    dialer2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mp2 = new MediaPlayer();

    public void onPlay1(View v)
    {
     Button playPause = (Button)v;
    if(mp2.isPlaying()){
if(mp2 != null){
     mp1.pause();
playPause.setText("Play");
dialer2.clearAnimation();
}
}else{
if(mp2 != null){
mp2.start();
playPause.setText("Pause");
load_animations2();
}
}
}


     void load_animations2()
     {
     RotateAnimation ranim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,      0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
         ranim.setDuration((mp2.getDuration() - mp2.getCurrentPosition()));
         ranim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

         ranim.setFillAfter(true);
         ranim.setFillEnabled(true);
         dialer2.startAnimation(ranim);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I quote: `new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,      0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);`

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html).

There, you'll see that's because you're trying to rotate by the same amount over more time!

You need to scale up the rotation amount proportionately if you want to the speed to stay the same.

Comment: but i cant figure out how to control the rotation amount

Comment: That's understandable, as the animation library can get confusing. Due to the way animations are implemented in Android, what you do is pass the rotation amount into the ctor- `360f` in your case. Let your new duration `d'` be a multiple of your previous duration `d' = dm`. Then your rotation amount correspondingly needs to be `360f*m`.